# C# Can/should a List<> of a class be a static member of the same class?

Tags: c#, list, class

My example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int a = 1;

    public static List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass.list.Add(new MyClass() { a = 5 });
        MyClass.list.Add(new MyClass() { a = 10 });
        foreach (MyClass item in MyClass.list) Console.WriteLine(item.a);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This code works, and shows that my list, which is statically defined within the MyClass class itself, is populating as I'd expect.

Is there any reason not to define my list in this manner?

Comment: Because public fields are a bad idea? Because global mutable state is a bad idea? It's fine in terms of typing though - and it's not entirely uncommon, e.g. for factory methods to return cached instances.

Comment: A static list has a fixed memory address that all threads can access. However, it is *mutable* and the items can be changed. These changes are likely to be concurrent which will cause thread safety issues. The `List<T>` and similar collections are not thread safe, you'd have to implement global locking (which would be awkward and dangerous also).

Comment: All of the comments and answers up to this time have been educational.  What I'm not understanding, I believe, is my own lack of OOP knowledge.  I will be doing more research.  I would give you all a +1, but my rep is still < 15.  Thank you.

Comment: @SlowCoder74: well the code you've written works (is correct). But insight has shown that a project containing too much of this kind of code is doomed to fail. So if you are planning to write a small project no problem, but it is not advisable to do so for an industrial project.

Answer (score 4):

Such a solution is used sometime, f.e. to implement the Singleton or Register-Resolve patterns.

But you should keep in mind that it's not well suited for multithread environment. Typically, a static collection should be private, and access methods (including property getter and setter) should be synchronized.

In additional, static fields/properties are difficult to an unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this code shows a lot of sign of (very) bad desing.

First of all one better **doesn't make fields public**. All other classes/object can now alter the value of that variable in objects. Perhaps you don't see much problems with that, but imagine that at one point in time you want to restrict the range of values that variable can have, or that it depends on the value of another field. Properties (with getters and setters) and methods are used to shield an field from external usage, they need to guarantee that the object always remains in a valid state.

Next about the list, again don't make such lists public - unless you are confident that there is no problem -. But furthermore using `static`s is by some researchers considered to be bad design as well. The list maintains a state, but since it is static, this is a **global state**. Global states are problematic since they don't allow (easy) unit testing, and can become problematic if for some reason the list should be not that global.

In case you really want to make some access point for data, you can perhaps consider making a class that stores such list and pass it around in your program.

---

There are a few exceptions, for instance the *Flyweight* pattern where one indeed maintains a global state. Those examples are merely used to increase performance. For instance:

```
public class FlyWeightInstance {

    private int value; //<- private field
    private static Dictionary<int,FlyWeightInstance> dic = new Dictionary<int,FlyWeightInstance>(); //<- private static cache

    private int FlyWeightInstance (int value) { // <-- private constructor
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static FlyWeightInstance (int value) {
        FlyWeightInstance res;
        if(!dic.TryGetValue(value,out res)) {
            res = new FlyWeightInstance(value);
            dic.Add(value,res);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm still learning a lot of the intricacies of C#.  I understand what you're saying about keeping the fields private, and using get/set properties to manage them.  (Sorry, I hit enter during edit, and it saved my comment).  Can you explain how placing the list in a different class benefits the code?

Comment: @SlowCoder74: this has not much to do with C# specifically. Over the years programmers have discovered insights in how to implement concepts in OO-programming languages. A nice result is the *Design Patterns* book of the *Gang of Four*.